# How can I get the gcc preprocessor to check if an expression evaluates to a value or nothing?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

I'm using gcc (specifically avr-gcc).

So this is my conundrum:

Let's say I have these defined somewhere:

```
#define THING_0_A 0
#define THING_0_B 1
#define THING_1_A 0
```

Then in a second file I have this:

```
#define CONCAT_(A,B,C) A ## B ## C
#define CONCAT(A,B,C) CONCAT_(A,B,C)

#define ID 0

#define THING_N(A) CONCAT(THING_,ID,A)
```

With this I now have a selection of expressions (still in the second file):

```
THING_N(_A) // evaluates to 0
THING_N(_B) // evaluates to 1
THING_N(_C) // evaluates to... nothing? Or undefined? Or THING_0_C?
```

Now, what I'm trying to work out is how to do this (also still in the second file):

```
#ifdef THING_N(_A)
    // Do something knowing that THING_N(_A) is defined (in this case THING_0_A)
#endif
```

Or:

```
#if THING_N(_A)
    // Do something knowing that the value THING_N(_A) evaluates to is defined and not just "nothing"
#endif
```

Of course neither of these work because #ifdef can't take an expression as an argument (and it would end up as "#ifdef 0" anyway), and THING_N(_A) evaluates to 0 within #if.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to make the preprocessor evaluate:

```
THING_N(_A) to true
THING_N(_B) to true
THING_N(_C) to false
THING_N(_D) to false
etc...
```

to be used in a conditional.

Comment: Sounds like a very typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You're quite right, it does sound like an XY problem (and I'm glad you mentioned it because I hadn't heard this name before), but in this case the above mentioned is my X. If someone can work out a Y then maybe I'll apply that Y to an X in the future. (i.e. I'm asking this for fun, curiosity, and the desire to better understand the way the c preprocessor works.)

Comment: If there is no practical purpose of the question, you can always add the "language-lawyer" tag, which means that you are just interested in the language mechanisms rather than trying to solve a real-world problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after doing a bunch of research and experimenting I've concluded that there is no solution to my question, and the reason for this is actually quite simple.

Given the setup I have in my question this is what the expressions are evaluated to:

```
THING_N(_A) -> THING_0_A -> 0
THING_N(_B) -> THING_0_B -> 1
THING_N(_C) -> THING_0_C -> 0 (Not nothing, as I previously thought.)
```

The piece of information I was missing earlier was that, as per c99 standard, undefined identifiers will be converted to 0, not nothing, making it impossible to distinguish between something undefined and something defined as 0.

Had the c99 standard chosen to make undefined identifiers evaluate to nothing, just like `#define FOO` makes FOO evaluate to nothing, then atturri's solution would have worked.

Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#if (1-THING_N(_A)-1 != 2)
```

This will be `true` for every value of `THING_N(_A)` (except for the value `-2`). It will be `false` only if `THING_N(_A)` is undefined or defined empty.

If there is a chance your macro can expand to `-2`, you can modify the second `1` and the `2` to other literals of your choice so that the basic idea holds.

Comment: I really like this idea. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me. The expression you wrote evaluates to true when THING_N(_A) is undefined. I'm guessing because it evaluates to `(1-THING_0_A-1 != 2)` instead of `(1- -1 != 2)` as intended.

Comment: And I just found out that the c99 standard says undefined identifiers are replaced with 0 (not nothing), which would give: `1-THING_0_A -1 != 2` -> `1-0 -1 != 2` -> `0 != 2` -> `1` (true). So that explains that.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the value with a known value, and check the result:

```
#define EMPTY_VAL_HELPER(VAL)  VAL ## 1
#define EMPTY_VAL(VAL)         EMPTY_VAL_HELPER(VAL)
```

Now you could do:

```
#if defined(FOO) && (EMPTY_VAL(FOO) == 1)
//FOO is defined, but empty
#endif

#if defined(FOO) && (EMPTY_VAL(FOO) != 1)
//FOO is defined, and not empty
#endif
```

Comment: The `#ifdef` conditional by its self would work perfectly if all I wanted to check was something like `#ifdef THING_0_A`, but that's not what my question is asking. What I'm actually curious about is the case where you have a macro and you want to check if the thing that macro evaluates to is defined or not. e.g. `#ifdef THING_N(_A)` where `THING_N(_A)` evaluates to `THING_0_A` (which is defined), and `#ifdef THING_N(_C)` where `THING_N(_C)` evaluates to `THING_0_C` (which is not defined).